# Display form in pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have two cshtml page one which has the link the makes the popup appear, and another with just the form data and would like to know how i would be able to display the form on the popup, as i am using MVC, to create the form,  the plage which has link on is in the `~/views/client/index.cshtml` while thr form is `~/views/fb/CreateOrEidt.cshtml` the colller is called "FB" and the methos to call is edit, it take the parameter Id

I have tried `@hmtl.renderpartial, @html.renderaction,  @hmtl.partial, @html.action,`
I have also tied these method with a { after the @ and the end, doesnt give me a error bust still doesn't display information

The error which i get is razor canot convert type object to void

Comment: How are you showing the popup window/thing in the browser? in other words, what happens in the main page in the browser when the link to the popup window is clicked?

Comment: when the popoup is made the background becomes darkers and popup come up in front

Comment: is the popup window part of jquery or another JS UI framework?

Comment: ITS jquery for the popuup action

Comment: The link in your main page must contain the relative url controller, then in the controller you I return this:

return this.PartialView("Details", model);

were Details is the partial view that is shown in the modal window.

Comment: the controller i wanr to call is cControlerr and the page is calling Acontroller, the model is in Ccoolroller, and when i call the model, it ask for the viewbags on the page as they are not set.

Comment: Do you see the partial view if you call it directly in the browser like this: http://server/app/ControllerName/PartialViewMethod

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve but from the error you've mentioned when calling Html.RenderAction you need to call using something like:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("ACTIONNAME");
}
```

Calling the other methods against an action view won't work.

If you're trying to display a view inside a popup though you want to be careful that you don't end up including your layout page etc as this is potentially not the look you're going for..!

The pattern I generally implement for things like this is to simply partial out the form bit that I need to reuse and call renderpartial to display this where I need it. This renders just the html I'm after then and not the whole view (+ layout(s)).